# How to apply a saved chart template to an existing chart?

Tags: excel, templates, charts, contour, excel-2011

I recently created a custom contour chart in excel to display my data colored with a heat-map color mapping. I'm using a Excel 2011 on a Mac. I can't find a way to reuse the saved template. The help instructs me to

1. Click the chart
2. On the Charts tab, under Change Chart Type, click Other, and then under Templates, click the chart template that you created.

There is no "Templates" Icon Group or an entry in the menu.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is really not obvious!

You have to scroll down the chart type list (toolbar Charts/button Other)
The saved templates are "hidden" at the very end of the list.

=>It is especially handy when you need to draw many of the same charts.

Yes, on the other side to save a chart as template you just need to:
- Right click on the finished chart
or
- Select the menu Chart/Save as template...

Answer (score 2):

Your saved templates are under Change Chart Type --> Other, you just have to scroll down below the radar charts. I know, not very intuitive....

Answer (score 0):

The answer did not work for my Mac version of Excel. First I needed to unhide the Library folder with a terminal command:
chflags nohidden ~/Library/
After that I needed to look up (Google) where Excel writes down its Chart Templates:
../Library/Application Support/Office/Chart Templates/
Only after that I was able to do what is suggested above, right-click an existing chart and save it as a template. Phew!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing.

I was able to apply the template by doing the following: 
/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office/Chart Templates/Your_template_Name.crtx

then go to Charts > Other > Scroll down to the bottom > Select your template(s) from the Templates section

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS I couldn't apply a saved template from any location. The templates have to be saved in the Excel's templates folder. To find it go to chart design -> change chart type -> Manage Templates...

Once you copy your templates to this folder, if you go to

chart design -> change chart type -> templates

you'll be able to apply your template.

Answer (score 0):

I had to put my templates here, perhaps because I also have a previous office version installed??

Mac OS, Excel v. 16.64

/Users/me/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/User Content.localized/Chart Templates.localized

(Search for Chart templates with system files revealed in Finder.)